# ViewSonic Monitor with DisplayLInk Docking Station not working

Tags: displaylink

I'm using a Thinkpad X1 Carbon 10th gen to connect to a DisplayLink docking station. The docking station is, in turn, connected to two ViewSonic monitors. I have used this exact same setup in the past (literally the same items) and it worked fine.

Recently, my monitors have not been displaying anything. My computer is connected to and recognizes the docking station. If I press the power button on the dock, my computer shuts off. The monitors themselves are receiving power. They just don't show anything. I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3.

What can I do about this?

Comment: Are you even using Ubuntu?  Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: @waltinator I'm using Ubuntu 22.04.3.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.